# Passing color as prop

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, styling

I'm creating a "profile card" component using an array and the `map()` function to render data dynamically instead of hardcoding it. I'd like each person's profile to have a different border color, so I'm attempting to pass the color as a prop to the styling of the component. In the array, there is a `color` key with one HEX value per person. I'm passing it down as a `prop` from the array. What I'd like to do is make something like `style={{border: '1px solid props.color'` but I'm not sure how to do so. Please let me know if you have any ideas!

Answer (score 3):

Use template literals. Something like this: `` style={{border: `1px solid ${props.color}`}} ``

Answer (score 2):

You could just add a template literal to add the prop to the string, e.g.

```
style={{border: `1px solid ${props.color}`}}
```